# Google Maps API load information

Tags: google-maps

With Google Maps API I can load information of a [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) file:

```
geoXml = new GGeoXml("http://exampleWeb.com/file.kml");
```

But, I can't load information of a public map in maps.google.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the KML for a *My Maps* page you need to get the link URL (top right) and then append *output=kml* to the URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00046920ee89136f6e1ab&ll=51.509928,-0.147281&spn=0.000666,0.001206&t=h&z=20&output=kml
```

It is the KML for http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=h&hl=en&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00046920ee89136f6e1ab&z=19